# Is there any way to configure heroku so that it can run a python app on its pseudo-termina using command-line arguments?

Tags: python, heroku, command-line-arguments

I have a run.py file that I would like to run using command-line arguments in heroku.
Rather than having the pseudo terminal provided by heroku to run my run.py file without me having to do anything, I would like to be able to type in a command in the following form:

```
run.py option_one
```

or

```
run.py option_two
```

or

```
run.py option_three
```

I'm pessimistic there's a solution to this issue at the moment, but I'd be grateful even for a confirmation from experienced heroku users that this is impossible

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: You want to do this manually? What do you mean by "the pseudo terminal provided by Heroku"? Are you talking about `heroku run`? Are you SSHing to a running Dyno? Are you using the Scheduler?